# Turn on Arduino Sim900 AT Command

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, sim900

I am having trouble turning on Sim900 on code. My project is to send data captured by sensor via the sim900 to server. I have tried the digitalWrite way and it does turn on the Sim900, however doing it that way does not send data to server.I am trying to find out if there is an AT command to turn it on. Here is my code to turn on and off. Just like the AT command for the GSMShieldPowerDown() function. thank you very much

```
void GSMShieldPowerDown()
{
   mySerial.println("AT+CPOWD=1");
}
void GSMShieldPowerUp()
{
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to send an AT command to it, if it's turned off?

Comment: ahhh yeah true. digitalWrite worked for me.. its working as intended now. thank you your help :)